# Statistics guessing game

Tags: gamma-distribution, games, game-theory

This is a game that I wanted to know the answer for.

**The Game**

There are many players in the game, who each get a guess.

There is a loss distribution, $L$, where:

$L$ ~ Gamma($\alpha$, $\beta$)

i.e. the value of $L$ will be drawn from a Gamma($\alpha$, $\beta$).

The idea is to choose an amount $X$ so that $(X-L)\geq0$.

The player who chooses the smallest $X$, such that $(X-L)\geq0$, will win.

I was wondering what would be the *best* guess that maximized a players chances of winning?

The obvious constraints for winning are that $X$ must be at least the size of $L$ and also that the minimum guess of all players will win.

--EDIT--
In the event of a tie between players, the winner will be randomly selected from this group (where each member of this group has an equal probability of being randomly selected).

Comment: If each player is behaving optimally, then they will all use the same strategy and therefore all will guess the same $X$. Therefore it is crucial that you explain what the payoff will be in case of a tie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two approaches. Both require certain subjective judgments in the form of priors or penalties, however. The optimal solution is denoted by $x^*$.

**@whuber 's warning: Subjective strategies are a bad idea if you can find an optimal strategy and assume that all players adopt it.**

**APPROACH 1**: Priors

Let there be $n$ players. We need to assume that the responses $X_i, i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, are i.i.d samples from a prior distribution on $\mathbb{R}_+$ that represents subjective knowledge about the opponents' guesses.

Denote the cumulative distribution function of the prior by $F_X(x)$, so that $P(X\leq x)=F_X(x)$.
Also, let $G_{\alpha, \beta}(x)$ denote the CDF of the Gamma random variable.

(EDITS: Based on the OP's comment, an additional constraint on $X_i$ was added)

We are now looking at the probability of winning:

$f(x)=P(\cap_i \color{red}{(X_i \not\in [L,x])} \cap (L \leq x))$

(which, by conditional probability, becomes:)

$=P[\cap_i (X_i \not\in [L,x])|L \leq x] P[L\leq x]$

$=\prod_i P[(X_i \leq L|L\leq x) \cup (X_i \geq x)] G_{\alpha, \beta}(x)$

$\Rightarrow f(x) = (1-\color{red}{c(x)})^n G_{\alpha, \beta}(x)$

Here, $c(x) = P(X_i \in [L,x] |L\leq x)$. You will need to get this as follows:

[image: Region of interest is the complement of the solid blue triangle]

So,

$c(x)=\int_{v=0}^x \int_{u=0}^{v} \text{jointpdf}_{X,L}(u,v) du dv$

$=\int_{v=0}^x \int_{u=0}^{v} p_X(u) p_L(v) du dv$

$=\int_{v=0}^x p_L(v) \int_{u=0}^{v} p_X(u)\; du dv$

This is assuming that $p_X(x)$ has mass only on $[0,\infty]$.

You're now in a position to proceed with setting the derivative to zero and finding the optimal solution.

**APPROACH 2**: Penalties

Here, the idea is to maximize your chances of exceeding $L$ subject to a norm constraint on your guess $x$.

First, pick a tradeoff penalty term $\lambda \geq 0$, then maximize:

$$f(x)=P(x\geq L) - \lambda x$$

The solution to this is:
$$f'(x^*)=0 \Rightarrow G_{\alpha, \beta}'(x^*)=\lambda$$

Assuming $G_{\alpha, \beta}'(x)=\dfrac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1}\exp(-\beta x)$, we get:

$$(\alpha-1)\log x^* - \beta x^* + \alpha \log \beta - \log \Gamma (\alpha) - \log \lambda = 0$$

This could be solved numerically.

Note that there is an implicit inequality constraint that $x \geq 0$. So you would have to discard negative values of $x^*$.

Notice that the forms of both solutions are similar. You can take the logarithm of the prior approach's solution to see this. The prior approach is a more principled way of choosing a penalty term.

Comment: Hey Salmonstrikes, thanks for the comprehensive response. I just had a quick point. I like the first approach where you assume a prior distribution for your competitors' guesses. Just a further question, how would you alter it so that rather than the probability of winning being equal to the intersection of all $(x<X_{i})$, but instead the intersection of those $X_{i}$ that are above $L$ (because you only need to be less than those $X_{i}$ that are larger than the loss size)?

Comment: Good point. The answer has been edited to reflect this additional constraint.

Comment: Also, you can extend this to tailor each prior differently. This could be useful, for instance, if you believe that some players take greater risks than others. As long as the players guess independently, you will get an objective like $f(x)=G_{\alpha, \beta}(x) \prod_i (1-F_{X_i}(x)+c_i)$

Comment: Game theory shows that a choice of priors should not be relevant. You proceed by assuming each player is attempting to optimize their expected loss. Any player who proceeds based on "subjective knowledge" of the other players' choices will be a loser in the long run.

Comment: So whuber, are you saying that all players simply set their guess at the expected value of the Gamma? Also, given that this is a single event, is 'long-run' a feasible concept?

Comment: I'm having some trouble calculating $c$. I convolve the two densities $X_{i}$ and $(-L)$ as you suggest to get $p_{Z}(z)$. But when I integrate $\int_{z=0}^{\infty}p_{Z}(x)\,dz$, the result is $1$. So when I put $c$ back into $f(x)=(1-F_{X}(x)+c)^{n}\ldots$ I have a problem as $(1-F_{X}(x)+c)\geq 1$ and raising to the power $n$ results in very large numbers?

Comment: Take the log of both sides: $\log f = n \log(K-F_X) + \log G$. Here, $K=1+c$. Taking derivatives: $f'/f=-np_X/(K-F_x)+p_L/G$. Set f' to zero to get the required equation: $nG p_X=p_L (K-F_X)$ (all functions of $x^\ast$, except for $K, n$). Whenever you run into problems with powers, take a logarithm and it should work out. Also, consider @whuber 's comment about optimal play, if you can work out an optimal strategy for all players.

Comment: Thanks @Salmonstrikes. I probably wasn't clear with my previous query. My issue is regarding the value I get for $c$. The function $f(x)=(1-F_{X}(x)+c)^{n}G_{\alpha,\beta}(x)$ represents the probability of winning? So should it not be bounded between $[0,1]$? When I calculate my $c$, the value is 1 and, as a result, $f(x)$ (depending on $n$) can be quite large. This leads me to believe that my calculation for $c$ is incorrect. I obtained $p_{Z}(z)$ by convolving $X_{i}$ and $(-L)$. The resulting distribution for $p_{Z}(z)$ is roughly symmetric with all its mass situated in $[0,\infty]$.

Comment: So when I integrate $\int_{z=0}^{\infty}p_{Z}(x)dx$ I obviously get $c=1$?

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll revisit my logic in a bit to see if something is wrong. Meanwhile, $Z=X_i-L>0$, always, doesn't sound right to me. This means that $X_i$ is distributed such that each player is guaranteed to draw a number greater than $L \sim \text{Gamma}$. What $X_i$ did you use?

Comment: I hadn't applied conditional probability correctly. You should now have the factor raised to $n$ less than one. The convolution has now been replaced by some other integral.